# Unity intercept Event Trigger IsInvoking()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and trying to intercept Event Trigger from another script.

1. I got gameobject with Event Trigger component set, and Drop event that is launching specific method correctly.
2. I am attaching another script to this gameobject that is supposed to intercept Event Trigger event fire.

In play mode script attaches to object and Event Trigger is found. It contains trigger data, but when specific event is fired it never triggers in update method in attached script. I assume the update is every frame and trigger fires earlier, or I am missing something? Any solution how to intercept Event Trigger event fire.

I was trying to use following script code:

```
    private EventTrigger eventTrigger;

    void Start()
    {
        eventTrigger = FindEventTrigger();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (eventTrigger != null)
        {
            if(eventTrigger.IsInvoking())
            {
                Debug.Log("Invoking");
            }
        }
    }

    private EventTrigger FindEventTrigger()
    {
        return CustomInstance.Instance.target.GetComponent<EventTrigger>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must subscribe to individual existing triggers and add listener.

```
private EventTrigger trigger;

var eventEntry = trigger.triggers.Find(x => x.eventID == EventTriggerType.Drop);
if (eventEntry != null)
 {
    eventEntry.callback.AddListener((data) => { OnPointerEventDelegate((PointerEventData)data); });
 }
```

This works as expected.